# Function returns post URLs rather than retrieving Facebook Graph API data

Tags: php, facebook

```
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
query_posts('&showposts=-1&order=ASC');

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $url = the_permalink();
        $json = file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count,%20comment_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20=%20%27' . $url . '%27' );
        $json_data = json_decode($json, false);
        echo $json_data->data[0]->total_count;
        echo '<br>';

    endwhile;
```

The above code, rather than returning the total share count, it returns the posts URLs.

How can I make it return the total_count value for each post ? I suspect line 6 needs to return URLs first before next line does the task..

Regards,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_permalink()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) doesn't return the post permalik, it prints the permalink. To assing the permalink value to `$url` variable you need to user [`get_the_permalink()`](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_the_permalink-not-working) instead:

```
$url = get_the_permalink();
```